# analyze android crash log

Tags: android, crash, native

I got a crash log stack from my app, and I can't understand how to read it. 
"#00" "#01" means the the depth of stack but what's the meaning of "[heap]" "[stack]"?

```
stack:
         ffd5ade0  ac59e9c8  [heap]
         ffd5ade4  f039e9a5  
         ffd5ade8  00000004  
         ffd5adec  2e736863  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
         ffd5adf0  00000001  
         ffd5adf4  ac5a32b8  [heap]
         ffd5adf8  ac5a32b0  [heap]
         ffd5adfc  00000013  
         ffd5ae00  ac59ee00  [heap]
         ffd5ae04  f74186db  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc_real+3530)
         ffd5ae08  00000004  
         ffd5ae0c  f7443dc0  /system/lib/libc.so
         ffd5ae10  f7417911  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc_real)
         ffd5ae14  ac5a2178  [heap]
         ffd5ae18  ac5a32b0  [heap]
         ffd5ae1c  00000001  
    #00  ffd5ae20  ffd5ae64  [stack]
         ffd5ae24  f03d2195  
    #01  ffd5ae28  f03d2185  
         ffd5ae2c  f038e005 
    #02  ffd5ae30  00000004  
         ffd5ae34  ac5a2178  [heap]
         ffd5ae38  00000001  
         ffd5ae3c  f038dfdd  
         ffd5ae40  0000000d  
         ffd5ae44  f03a40c3
```

Comment: Does the crash report give you a stack trace? That would be far more useful to diagnose the problem. What you're looking at there is just a list of object memory addresses. Some are on the stack, some on the heap.

Comment: @AndrewFielden I have analyzed stack trace and got all valuable information from that but that's not enough to solve the issue. So I have to look for information from stack and register. Do you know the meaning of [heap] and [stack] on the side?